# How do I use RGB color in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, rgb

I am trying to use it like this but it is giving me no color on text.

```
Color.fromARGB(1, 239 ~/ 255, 58 ~/ 255, 121 ~/ 255)
```

Comment: The `~/` operator would make all your RGB values 0 and return a black color anyway. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Try using

```
Color.fromRGBO(38, 38, 38, 0.4)
```

Where `r` is for `Red`, `g` is for Green, `b` is for `Blue`and `o` is for `opacity`

Example:

```
Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: double.infinity,
                color: Color.fromRGBO(38, 38, 38, 0.4),
                child: Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ))
```

Comment: I tried doing this, but I'm getting the following error -

The method 'fromRGBO' isn't defined for the type 'Color'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'fromRGBO'.dartundefined_method

Answer (score 7):

I am using this code block for a personal project of mine in order to show text with a specific color using `Color.fromRGBO`, first parameter is `Red`, second is `Green`, third is `Blue` and last parameter defines the `Opacity`.

```
Text(
    "This is a sample text",
     textAlign: TextAlign.center,
     style: TextStyle(
             color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 179, 102, 1)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also use the hexadecimal representation `Color(0XFF212845)`.
**Comment from source**

> /// In other words, if AA is the alpha value in hex, RR the red value in hex,
>     /// GG the green value in hex, and BB the blue value in hex, a color can be
>     /// expressed as `const Color(0xAARRGGBB)`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to specify opacity as a double value between 0.0 (transparent) and 1.0 (fully opaque), use `Color.fromRGBO()`. The opacity value is the last parameter.

```
Color.fromRGBO(int r, int g, int b, double opacity)
```

But if you want to specify opacity as an integer value between 0 (transparent) and 255 (fully opaque), use `Color.fromARGB()`. The opacity value is the first parameter.

```
Color.fromARGB(int a, int r, int g, int b)
```

The `r`, `g`, `b` parameters of both methods are integer values between 0 and 255.

Answer (score 0):

increase alpha(first argument) so you can see it.
example:-
  **color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 0, 0)**